# How to redirect audio from server to client in RDP session using virtual audio device driver?

Tags: windows, audio

I want to create an application for redirecting the audio from server to client and playing the audio through client's speaker when running  a song through player at server

How to achieve this by creating a new virtual audio device driver?How to set the virtual audio device as a default device for each user mode session? How to get the audio stream from virtual audio device driver and writing it into RDP virtual channel? I need to support both windows XP and vista.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is already built-in in RDP version 5.1 and later (Windows XP). See this link on how to activate it (the link is for Windows 2008 Server, but it applies to earlier versions of Windows as well): [How to enable Audio Redirection in RDP (Remote Desktop Protocol)](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/windows-2003-2008-enable-audio-over-rdp/)

Answer (score 0):

Sound redirect using RDP has been carried out in rdesktop, which is a project in Linux. But it can provide some tips in this. I hope this can help you. Well, you can get rdesktop in http://www.cendio.com/seamlessrdp/

Comment: Answers which just contain links are [considered bad practice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). Please summarize the content here (don't copy/paste) so the answer can stand on its own. If you don't you run the risk of your answer being removed, especially if the link ever dies.